# CSS-Animations: nested animation for a walk cycle

Tags: css, animation, nested, keyframe

How can I turn on and off a secondary animation in nested elements for a walk cycle?

I want to animate a bug crawling around, stopping, turning around, walk, etc. My bug consists of a div with a body PNG and two PNGs of three legs each. I stacked the three PNGs inside the bug div on top of each of each other and using a little CSS looped keyframe animation, I rotate the leg PNGs a few degrees so that it looks quite convincingly like a walk. This works fine.

I can also move the whole bug (a div containing three imgs) across the screen with a keyframe animation while the little legs are moving. Great so far!

But: when the bug div pauses (defined by its animation), the leg cycle *inside* of the bug div needs to stop as well. How can I address that? I cannot stop the leg animation with another animation, right?

Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround myself:

1. created an image of the resting bug with legs in resting position
2. apply the same positioning and animation as the bug with wiggling legs. So that they move exactly on top of each other.
3. create an additional, independed animation for each of the bugs that switches the opacity on and off at the appropriate time so that the static bug is only visible when it does not move and that the wiggling bug is only visible when it moves. The length of these animations have the same timing and stops as the animation for the movement.